SQL Server management Studio does not show Index recommendation
I have installed SQL Server management studio version 20 (and also tried with 19 and 18) and surprisingly unable to see the Missing Index Hints while explaining a SQL Query. Whenever i receive a SQL plan I just open it with the SSMS and could see the missing index details although the tables are not available in my DB. Can you suggest which feature is not installed in my system or which option to enable to check the missing indexes.


I have attached the latest software installed in my system.

Please paste your full query here also.

Don't worry, you're not miissing much by not seeing it. More of a hint that there might be something wrong with the index design, than an actual instruction about what to do.

Seeing a "Scan" does not automatically mean that SQL Server will suggest an index. Furthermore, just because SQL Server suggests a missing index - it doesn't always mean it is the necessary or best index.
A missing index is suggested not because a "scan" shows up - but because SQL Server sees that you have a properly formed where search argument that can use an index, it sees that the seek option to get to your data would be more efficient than a scan and it sees that the columns you are returning are sufficient for an index. There are a lot of heuristics that go into the suggestion.
I've requested a few more things in comments - but I am assuming here that you just don't have a missing index opportunity per SQL Server's internal analysis.
